# How to create canvas effect with Imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to replicate the canvas texture style effect on a photo using the Imagick php class as seen here under the heading 'texture':

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/

Using the command line it can be achieved like this:

```
composite texture_fabric.gif  pagoda_sm.jpg \
            -tile   -compose Hardlight    photo_texture.jpg
```

However I am using the 'Imagick' php class for ImageMagick and I can't seem to work out how to tile the texture.

I have tried:

```
$im = new Imagick("source.jpg")
$img2 = new Imagick("texture.gif");
$im->compositeImage($img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_HARDLIGHT, 0, 0);
```

But all I end up with is the texture image composited on the the source image in the top left corner.

How can I recreate the effect in the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the imagick php there is http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.textureimage.php
You may not be able to do what you want with Imagick as it has limited options.
A bit of lateral thinking:
Make a canvas the size of the image and tile the texture across it then composite it?

You could do it with ( untested ):

```
exec("composite texture_fabric.gif pagoda_sm.jpg -tile -compose Hardlight photo_texture.jpg");
```

Comment: Simple... I was really hoping that there was a built in function for this but as you say, it appears not.  I used your first solution as I wanted to stay within Imagick as much as possible.  Many thanks!